# What's the security impact of tampering with Google OAuth continue parameter?

Tags: appsec, google, oauth

What's the security issue of this scenario related to tampering with the **continue** parameter:

1. Go to: `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=[service name]&passive=true&continue=https://[service].google.com/?continue=https://efbrcko.com/&ltmpl=ae`
2. When I sign in, I get redirected to `efbrcko.ba/?state=[long random char text]`

What is the **state** value used for? Could this be considered a vulnerability, e.g. token hijacking or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [*basic HTML* web version of Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/) and have look at the hyperlinks inside the mail, you'll find your answer.

The issue happens because there are many open redirects for Google, since they don't consider this a security vulnerability.